# AQGridView iPad Orientation change cell resizing

Tags: aqgridview

So I've been banging my head in the wall trying to figure this out. Here is what I need essentially:

I have an AQGridView that is used to display images(UIImageView) in either portrait or landscape orientation. If orientation is portrait then the image just takes up the whole screen (768x1024) and that part is working just nice. However, in landscape what I need is for 2 images to be side by side (512x768). Now when orientation changes from portrait to landscape of course 2 cells are shown instead of one, which is nice but I can't seem to make the right image be precisely next to the right side of the left image. I've tried several things, I suspect:
- (CGRect) gridView: (AQGridView *) gridView adjustCellFrame: (CGRect) cellFrame withinGridCellFrame: (CGRect) gridCellFrame

will be my savior here but I just can't seem to make it work correctly. Any ideas? Anyone who has had and solved a similar problem? Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
        [gView setResizesCellWidthToFit:YES];
        [gView setSeparatorStyle:AQGridViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```